# Converting an array of strings into a key-value pair

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array as the value of a hash:

```
:params=>[":centre_id", ":id"]
```

I am trying to find a way to convert each element of the array to something like this:

```
:centre_id => 1
:id => 1
```

I tried loads of different ways but I can't seem to find a nice clean way to do it:

```
"#{route[:params].map {|x| x.parameterize.underscore.to_sym => '1'}}"
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
-{"controller"=>"venues", "action"=>"activity, {:centre_id=>1, :id=>1}"}
+{"controller"=>"venues", "action"=>"activity", "centre_id"=>"1", "id"=>"1"} << this one

    string or symbol doesn't matter does it?
```

Using this:

```
expect(route[:request_method] => route[:path]).to route_to "#{route[:controller]}##{route[:action]}, #{Hash[route[:params].map {|x| [x.sub(/\A:/,'').to_sym, 1] }]}"
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does your input data look like?

Comment: @tadman 
  [{:request_method=>:get, :path=>"/leisure/1/activity/1", :controller=>"venues", :params=>[":centre_id", ":id"], :controller_constant=>"VenuesController", :action=>"activity"},

Comment: i want to achieve something like       get("/game/1").should route_to("game#show", :id => 1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do as below :-

## Ruby 2.1 or above, use below :-

```
route[:params].map {|x| [x.sub(/\A:/,'').to_sym, 1] }.to_h
# => {:centre_id => 1, :id => 1}
```

## Ruby 2.0 or below, use below :-

```
Hash[route[:params].map {|x| [x.sub(/\A:/,'').to_sym, 1] }]
# => {:centre_id => 1, :id => 1}
```

Comment: @tadman Thanks for teaching.. sweet thing. I am not well in regex, so always try to avoid.. :-(

Comment: It's something you should make a point to practice. A site like [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) is a great way to test and learn. Once you've got a handle on them you'll find they come in handy all the time.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your help, but it renders error        undefined method `to_h' for [[:centre_id, 1], [:id, 1]]:Array

Comment: The `to_h` method might be Rails specific. An alternative is to use `Hash[ ... ]` instead of `(...).to_h`

Comment: @user3868832 your Ruby version ?

Comment: @tadman, Arup, thank you again. While you have answered my question I have added additional details of what i am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If

```
h = { :params=>[":centre_id", ":id"], :animals=>[":dog", ":cat", ":pig"] }
```

one of the following may be helpful:

```
h.merge(h) { |_,v,_| Hash[v.map { |s| [s[1..-1].to_sym,1] }] }
  #=> {:params=>{:centre_id=>1, :id=>1}, :animals=>{:dog=>1, :cat=>1, :pig=>1}}
```

or

```
Hash[h.keys.map { |k| h.delete(k).map { |s| [s[1..-1].to_sym,1] } }.flatten(1)]
  #=> {:centre_id=>1, :id=>1, :dog=>1, :cat=>1, :pig=>1}
```

The second modifies `h`. If you don't want that to happen, you'll need to `h.dup` first.

If `a` is an array, you can replace `Hash[a]` with `a.to_h` with Ruby 2.1+.